# design patent d579373 - patent infringement

Tags: patent-infringement, design-patent, usd579373

I have a jewelry design that is simply 3 interlocking solid silver rings that can be used as a baby's teething ring.  I have been told that I am in infringement of design patent d579373 ..which is 3 hollow silver circular tubes linked together and sold as a baby's teething ring.   It is possible that a design as simple as 2 or 3 interlocking rings can be patented...and anything made using 3 interlocking circles is considered infringement?

Comment: Anna,
While sites like this can provide some educational guidance, it should not be relied on for addressing real life problems. Because you've been accused of infringement you should consult with an actual attorney. Since design patents can be a bit quirky I'd suggest you talk to someone who is both a patent attorney and has litigation experience. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your interlocking rings might have been anticipated also by https://www.google.com/patents/US6484536 "Interlocking Rings" :

> "**ABSTRACT** An item of jewelry preferably in the form of a ring having a
>   first ring portion mechanically interconnected to a second ring
>   portion. Preferably each ring portion includes a plurality of
>   alternating radially inward linking segments and radially outward
>   linking segments. The radially inward linking segments include a
>   groove which mates with a tongue formation on the radially outward
>   linking segments."

from the **DESCRIPTION**

> "**TECHNICAL FIELD** The present invention is generally directed to an
>   interlocking connection for two or more components of an item of
>   jewelry, and more particularly to an interlocking connection for two
>   or more ring portions which are combined into a single finished ring."